# passing modelview matrix and projection matrix values in android rendering

Tags: android, opengl-es, rendering, qcar-sdk, rajawali

i am trying to render an animated model by using Min3d or Rajawali rendering frameworks for android,but  even after getting the modelview matrix and projection matrix from QCAR i have no clue how to pass them to these frameworks so that they render in real world coordinates.
anyone have any clue that how can i pass model view matrix and projection matrix values?.
i tried a lot of things but came up with no solution,can anyone help me with that.
any help will be welcomed ,,, 
thanks in advance.

Comment: If you 'tried a lot of things', why don't you show what you tried, and say what your results were? I don't think anyone's going to write you a full tutorial on 3D transformations, so it would be helpful to give a reference point of what knowledge you're already bringing to the question.

Comment: so my current problm is that these two framework qcar and rajawali when rendered together ,the result is nothing...i mean nothing is rendered.how can these two can be rendered together and then exactly where i have to pass value of modelview matrix?and i don't want full tutorial,i jst want if any one tried this can give me the clue

Answer (score 1):

Mr Yogi.

This issue discussion on github helped me to solve this problem: https://github.com/MasDennis/Rajawali/issues/63

I know, that you have participated in this thread but I want to post an answer because it can be helpful for others.